# Decompress a GZIP CSV file on client side with Pako.js

Tags: javascript, gzip, fetch-api, pako

#### Problem

**I want to load a large gzipped CSV file using the Fetch API and Pako.js with client-side code.** This is the code I was using:

```
const res = await fetch('www.example.com/large.csv.gzip');
let raw = await res.text();
raw = pako.inflate(raw);
console.log(raw);
```

I got an error without any stack trace:

```
Uncaught (in promise) unknown compression method
```

#### Attempted Research

I found some examples, but they didn't relate to CSV files, the Fetch API, or both:

- [Using Axios Requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55983672/axios-request-gzip-data-from-php-api/55986366#55986366)
- [Compressing JSON files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47389750/pako-on-client-side-with-java-on-server-side)
- [Using WASM-Gzip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65998768/loading-large-compressed-json-in-html/66309156#66309156)
- [Using Base-64 Strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14620769/decompress-gzip-and-zlib-string-in-javascript)

#### Environment

Firefox 108.0.2 (64-bit)

Pako.js version 2.1.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came across a [Codepen](https://codepen.io/vladpolonskiy/pen/LwQVxb) that was using XHR requests and setting the response type to an array buffer.

So I tried that with the Fetch API and the code worked!

```
const res = await fetch('www.example.com/large.csv.gzip');
let raw = await res.arrayBuffer();
raw = pako.inflate(raw);
console.log(raw); // Prints CSV file content successfully
```